# Is it possible to change ft_min_word_len on a Rackspace Client account?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, rackspace-cloud

I am using a Rackspace Client account (no shell access, ability to modify core config files, etc.) and I need to find a way to decrease MySQL's ft_min_word_len from 3 to 2.  Is this possible without being able to access... pretty much... anything?  Is there something I can do from the MySQL server to change this setting?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured this out by now, but as of right now, no.  I also need it changed.

I've contacted support several times to no avail.

I found [one support/suggestion thread on the subject](http://feedback.rackspace.com/forums/71021-product-feedback/suggestions/3530802-mysql-configuration-management) and added a comment.  I suggest you do the same.  Hopefully it receives some attention from Rackspace.

As a side note, the [default for ft_min_word_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) is actually 4.